# Why does Ni and Fe alloy that forms the outer core produce earth magnetic field?

Tags: geomagnetism, core

Earth magnetic field is produced by the convection currents of Ni and Fe in the outer core, but why should the movement of Fe and Ni produce a magnetic field? Fe and Ni form a metallic compound, made of ions as well as electrons, thus it should be neutral and should not cause any electric currents while moving.

Comment: By way of analogy, what you are saying is equivalent to saying is that the copper wires in your house or apartment are electrically neutral and thus should not cause any electric currents. The copper wires aren't even moving! It appears that you have not done any research on this topic.